# (よ)うが～まいが / (よ)うと～まいと vs かどうか

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances

I'm currently studying some N1 grammar, and I actually find it pretty hard getting a feel of the grammar patterns.

I saw this pattern in my Anki deck:

> わたしは他人の話に耳を傾けたわけではないんですが、むこうはきかれて**いようがいまいが**、気にとめていなかったのです。
>
> It’s not that I listened to what is not meant for me. They were quite oblivious of
> who heard them and who did not. (Not my translation.)

I looked up for another sample sentence and found [this](https://jn1et.com/youga-maiga-n1/):

> 気持ち悪いと言われようが言われまいが、私はオタクを貫く。
>
> Whether or not I get told that it's 気持ち悪い (I don't know how to best
> translate this: disgusting? gives them a bad feeling?), I'm a geek.

My question is, if I replace this pattern with かどうか like in the following sentences:

> 気持ち悪いと言われるかどうか、私はオタクを貫く。
>
> わたしは他人の話に耳を傾けたわけではないんですが、むこうはきかれているかどうか　(seems grammatically wrong to me)、気にとめていなかったのです。

How will it change the sentence? Will it feel less "written style" and more "spoken style"? More casual? Or is it even a valid replacement? Also, in what setting is this grammar pattern usually seen? I've read a couple of news articles and some editorials, and so far, I haven't encountered them yet. Looking up grammar patterns like this in the corpus gives me a hard time because there's something sandwiched in between よう and まい.

Answer (score 0):

(1) 気持ち悪いと言われるかどうか、私はオタクを貫く doesn't make sense while (2) むこうはきかれているかどうか 気にとめていなかった is fine.

が as in ようが（まいが）is a conjunction, thus ようが（まいが）functions as an adverbial phrase. However, か（どうか）doesn't have a conjunction, thus, doesn't function as an adverbial phrase but just an equivalent to a noun.

In the second example, きかれているかどうか is the object for the verb 気に留めていなかった, (and you can insert を after it). However, the first example doesn't have a verb that corresponds with 気持ち悪いと言われるかどうか, which is essentially a noun.